# Recursive download articles and dump to MongoDB

Tags: python, wordpress, mongodb

This is simple code that recursively downloads articles from the public WordPress API:

```
import requests

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.wp

payload = {
    'number': 100
}

url = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/{site_id}/posts'
response = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
found = response['found']
posts = response['posts']
print 'found {number} posts'.format(number=found)
db.posts.insert_many(posts)

def get_next_page(offset):
    print 'Inserted we have {left} posts left to go'.format(left=abs(found-offset))
    response = requests.get(url, params= {
        'number': 100,
        'offset': offset
    }).json()

    db.posts.insert_many(response['posts'])

    if int(response['found']) > offset:
        get_next_page(offset + 100)


get_next_page(100)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic for getting 100 posts is duplicated for the case of the initial load and subsequent loads with an offset. It would be better to refactor in a way to eliminate the duplicated logic:

```
params = {'number': 100}
offset = 0

while True:
    response = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    found = response['found']
    posts = response['posts']       
    db.posts.insert_many(posts)
    print 'Inserted {number} posts'.format(number=len(posts))
    offset += 100
    if offset >= found:
        break
    print 'We have {left} posts left to go'.format(left=found-offset)       
    params['offset'] = offset
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code follows most of PEP8.

However:

- Lines should be a maximum of 79 characters. The exception to this is comments, at 72.
- Operators should have a space either side of them. `2 * 2`.   The exception to this is to show precedence: `2*2 + 2`.
- You should not have any spaces around the `=` when passing arguments:

  ```
  response = requests.get(url, params= {
  ```

Your code looks really good otherwise.

---

It may be worth removing the need to parse key-words to `str.format`:

```
print 'found {number} posts'.format(number=found)
```

It's good, but a bit long-winded.

---

Also, I would recommend not relying on globals in `get_next_page`. If you only want to pass `found` once you can do this:

```
def get_next_page(found):
    def inner(offset):
        # Same as before
        if int(response['found']) > offset:
            inner(offset + 100)
     return inner

get_next_page(found)(100)
```

---

And finally, if you are planning on using this on a very large amount of data, where you would have to use `get_next_page` a lot, I would recommend not using recursion.

Have a look at `sys.getrecursionlimit()`. It tells you how many times you can recurse. My limit is 1000, for example.

For more info, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001/2044866).

Comment: Can you explain why using `inner`?